# PySpark how to convert an rdd to string

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to pass coordinates in an url but I need to convert the rdd to a string and separate with a semicolon.

```
all_coord_iso_rdd.take(4)

[(-73.57534790039062, 45.5311393737793),
 (-73.574951171875, 45.529457092285156),
 (-73.5749282836914, 45.52922821044922),
 (-73.57501220703125, 45.52901077270508)]

type(all_coord_iso_rdd)
pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD
```

Results lookin for:

```
"-73.57534790039062,45.5311393737793;-73.574951171875,45.529457092285156,
 -73.5749282836914,45.52922821044922;-73.57501220703125,45.52901077270508"
```

The form of my URL should be as follows:

```
http://127.0.0.1/match/v1/driving/-73.57534790039062,45.5311393737793; -73.574951171875,45.529457092285156,-73.5749282836914,45.52922821044922;-73.57501220703125,45.52901077270508
```

Comment: `take()` returns a value. It doesn't modify the rdd. Try `x = all_coord_iso_rdd.take(4)`. Then `print(type(x))` - you'll see that it's a list (of tuples). Then just convert it to string.

Comment: Thank you @pault but how to convert this list of tuples to a simple string?

Comment: You'll have to play around with it a bit but I think `";".join([",".join(map(str, item)) for item in x])` will get you close (if not exactly what you need), where `x = all_coord_iso_rdd.take(4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the snippet you posted `all_coord_iso_rdd` is an `rdd`, where each row is a `tuple(float, float)`. Calling `take(n)` returns `n` records from the `rdd`.

```python
x = all_coord_iso_rdd.take(4)
print(x)
#[(-73.57534790039062, 45.5311393737793),
# (-73.574951171875, 45.529457092285156),
# (-73.5749282836914, 45.52922821044922),
# (-73.57501220703125, 45.52901077270508)]
```

The value returned is simply a list of tuples of floating point numbers. To convert it into the desired format, we can use `str.join` inside of a list comprehension.

First, you need to convert the `float`s to `str` and then we can join the values in each tuple using a `","`. We use `map(str, ...)` to map each value to a `str`.

This yields:

```python
print([",".join(map(str, item)) for item in x])
#['-73.5753479004,45.5311393738',
# '-73.5749511719,45.5294570923',
# '-73.5749282837,45.5292282104',
# '-73.575012207,45.5290107727']
```

Finally join the resultant list using `";"` to get your desired output.

```python
print(";".join([",".join(map(str, item)) for item in x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure spark way of doing the same (may be useful for larger 
rdds/different use cases):

```
list=[(-73.57534790039062, 45.5311393737793),(-73.574951171875, 45.529457092285156),\
 (-73.5749282836914, 45.52922821044922),(-73.57501220703125, 45.52901077270508)]

rdd=sc.parallelize(list)
rdd.map(lambda row: ",".join([str(elt) for elt in row]))\
   .reduce(lambda x,y: ";".join([x,y]))
```